# JavaScript nested element loops and append bug?

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, appendchild

I have four different elements,

```
<div id='div1'>One: </div>
<div id='div2'>Two: </div>
<span id='span1'>Test 1</span>
<span id='span2'> and 2</span>
```

and I want to append both `span` elements to both `div` elements by doing,

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');

div.forEach(function(currentDiv){
  span.forEach(function(currentSpan){
    currentDiv.appendChild(currentSpan);
  });
});
```

The expected output is,

```
<div id='div1'>One: 
    <span id='span1'>Test 1</span>
    <span id='span2'> and 2</span>
</div>
<div id='div2'>Two: 
    <span id='span1'>Test 1</span>
    <span id='span2'> and 2</span>
</div>
```

But for some reason the `span` elements aren't appended to both `div` elements, but only to the last `div`. Any reason why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Because they are the _same_ child, and will instead be moved from one to the other. You need to clone the span's to get two in each div

Comment: You are telling to append specific elements to a specific element. You have to create new elements or clone them and append.

Comment: Oh, I should probably have read the documentation better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, as they are the same child, they will be [moved from one element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to the other.

You need to [clone the `span`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to get two in each `div`.

Here is a sample

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');

div.forEach(function(currentDiv, index){
  span.forEach(function(currentSpan){    
    if (index == 0) {
      currentDiv.appendChild(currentSpan);
    } else {
      var clone = currentSpan.cloneNode(true);
      clone.id += index;
      currentDiv.appendChild(clone);
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='div1'>One: </div>
<div id='div2'>Two: </div>
<span id='span1'>Test 1</span>
<span id='span2'> and 2</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted this answer because of it providing a way to use elements with set `id` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to clone the `span`

```
currentDiv.appendChild(currentSpan.cloneNode());
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

But in your case, that would lead to duplicated `id` attributes. If possible, use `class`es instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works when I set the `deep` argument to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
You would need to clone the nodes. Modified your code to clone each span before appending to div element. However you might also want to change the attributes value like id.

var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');

div.forEach(function(currentDiv){
  span.forEach(function(currentSpan){
    currentDiv.appendChild(currentSpan.cloneNode(true));
  });
});
```